tensorflow-gpu installation failed in colab
When I tried to install tensorflow-gpu in google colab ,it gives me this error:
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
Using cached tensorflow-gpu-2.12.0.tar.gz (2.6 kB)
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed
× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

tensorflow-gpu is a deprecated package, tensorflow already contains GPU support. Please always read the error message in detail.

Google colab already comes with tensorflow installed, so you don't need to install it again

I know, but I'm talking about tensorflow-gpu not tensorflow

Yes you don't need to install it because in colab it is configured to use gpu acceleration if a gpu is available so just go to runtime->change runtime type -> hardware accelerator and then change it to gpu
